# Using link_to_function with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have view form like this:

```
<% @company.projects.each do |project| %>
<%= link_to_function project.title, "toggle_information_for('#{project.id}')" %>
<br />
  <div id="information_for_<%= project.id %>">
  <p><%= project.information %></p>
  <br/>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And I have this jQuery function:

```
function toggle_information_for(project){
$("#information_for_"+project).toggle();
}
```

How can I make link_to like anchor?

For example:

If I click to project.title, then opening information about project by toggle_information_for function and url changed to /#project_id. How can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your question, but you're looking to call the toggle_information_for JS function, you need to write your `link_to` like this:

```
<%= link_to_function project.title, "javascript:toggle_information_for('#{project.id}')" %>
```

If you're looking to add the project ID to your URL, try:

```
function toggle_information_for(project){
    $('#information_for_' + project).toggle();
    location.hash = project;
}
```

Hopefully that helps. And while this works, I'd recommend getting rid of the direct JS call in the `href` of the link and add an event handler directly in your JS by writing your `link_to` like this:

```
<%= link_to_function project.title, "#information_for_#{project.id}" %>
```

And writing your JavaScript like this:

```
function toggle_information_for(e){
    $(e.target.href).toggle();
    location.hash = project;
}

$('#wrapper_div').delegate('click', 'a', toggle_information_for);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise adding a class and then separating the jQuery logic from the html.

```
<% @company.projects.each do |project| %>
<div class="info_for" id="info_for_<%= project.id %>">
<%=project.title%>
<br />
  <div>
  <p><%= project.information %></p>
  <br/>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And then some jQuery

```
$('.info_for').click(function(){
   $('div',this).toggle();
});
```